# How can I change the time of a page

Tags: onenote

In OneNote 2013 I've got only the option to set the page time per half hour. How can I set it per minute?

Comment: Joel, you're getting downvotes/votes to close on your questions because they aren't programming questions and the Stack Overflow community chooses to be fairly strict over what is on-topic to keep the answer base clean and noise free.  One of the other stack exchange forums might be a better fit.

Comment: Thanks GarethJ Sorry for being sort of off-topic, it was also sort of a feature request

Comment: Feature requests are best served at http://onenote.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a free macro that would do this: [Set Page Time](http://omeratay.com/onetastic/?r=macroland&id=3EA5C11F993E474BA405C191F42B54F1)

Comment: Thanks, it almost works (check the page of the plugin please)! I really hope that things function will end up in OneNote. My work PC won't allow me to install onetastic